# Error message on fresh Laravel Lumen installation

Tags: laravel, lumen

On my **fresh** Laravel Lumen installation my log files filles up with this error.

```
local.ERROR: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getRoutes() on array in Command line code:1
```

Laravel/Lumen version 8.x

How can I fix this?